# jsonRPCClient.php states its served a 401 error response

Tags: bitcoind, client, json-rpc

When I execute my php file from the command line I get this:

```
<pre>
PHP Warning:  fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:8332/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required
 in /home/brian/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc16/jsonRPCClient.php on line 132
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://b:a@127.0.0.1:8332/' in /home/brian/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc16/jsonRPCClient.php:140
Stack trace:
#0 /home/brian/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc16/index1.php(12): jsonRPCClient->__call('getinfo', Array)
#1 /home/brian/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc16/index1.php(12): jsonRPCClient->getinfo()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/brian/Desktop/VH2_apache2/host02/btc16/jsonRPCClient.php on line 140
```

---

My php file looks like this:

```
<?php
  require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';

  $bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/',true);
  #$param = array(
  #'c418518d5ffccd947e377ab7e589f684d83e6df1af8f397cc11848ac8a78f0dd',
  #'1');

  #$return1 = $bitcoin->getrawtransaction('c418518d5ffccd947e377ab7e589f684d83e6df1af8f397cc11848ac8a78f0dd','1')

  echo "<pre>\n";
  print_r($bitcoin->getinfo()); echo "\n";
  #print_r($return1['0']); echo "\n";
  #echo "Received: ".$bitcoin->getreceivedbylabel("Your Address")."\n";
  echo "</pre>";
?>
```

---

My webpage with apache2 appears blank that uses the php file I made.
I am using the -txindex parameter when I launch bitcoind.

But I am able to use bitcoin-cli to interact with bitcoind

```
Iv'e used:
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction c418518d5ffccd947e377ab7e589f684d83e6df1af8f397cc11848ac8a78f0dd 1

and:
bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

---

Also my bitcoin.conf looks like this:

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
txindex=1
server=1
```

---

Also note that I substituted the usernames and passwords to hide them.

My question is why can I use bitcoin-cli and get no error, but when I try to use the jsonRPCClient.php I get the error 401 Authorization Required and how do I fix the error?

Comment: Error 401 means bad user/password. I notice that the password is `pass` in your config file, and it's `password` in your config file. Does that reflect the contents of your config/php files?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, I replaced my password and username listed on this forum to maintain security of the bitcoin core on my computer. The password and username I used on my computer match with those in the config file and I have checked many times.

Comment: I dunno what to tell you. [Bad user/pass](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/4c4f1b4721c7c8ef54eb5eea0208482352503d24/src/rpcserver.cpp#L917) is what triggers the error.

Comment: Have you restarted your client since putting the username and password in the conf file?

Comment: I think so, I have re-started my php script and bitcoind as well, and the wierd thing is that it worked at one point.

Comment: I've now discovered its partially caused by leaving armory bitcoin wallet manager open for days.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to this open issue.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9661

I was running bitcoind on Ubuntu 16.

I had the similar issue when I had `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in the config file. All I got is 401 error when I called the jaon-rpc api.

I found a workaround by providing `-rpcuser=REPLACED -rpcpassword=REPLACED` when I launched the bitcoind.

Hope this is useful.

One more thing, instead of debug from your rpc client in PHP. Maybe try it with `curl` first. HTTP 401 clearly is an authentication issue, using `curl` is much easier for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your RPC username and password are correct, also make 
sure that your username and password don't contain (#) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check which `bitcoin.conf` configuration file the `bitcoind` daemon is using. Its explicitly shown on bootstrapping.

This would arise if you change default bitcoin-core installation path on setup.

This way you won't need to pass the user/pwd via cli on service start.